# Shiny App not finding PDF file in www folder

Tags: file, web

I am trying to create a simple button, link, and/or viewing pane in my Shiny App that allows users to download a pre-existing PDF file that I have saved in my www folder (code below). The App keeps coming back with the error message "File not Found".  However, when I check that the file exists with file.exists("www/sample_label.pdf") it returns TRUE. I can't for the life of me figure out where the problem is coming from.  The code works if I try a url like "https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf". Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Vaccine Label"),
  
    mainPanel(
    downloadButton("downloadLabel", label = "Download Label", class = NULL, icon = shiny::icon("download")),
    br(),
      tags$a("Download Label", href = "www/sample_label.pdf"),
    br(),
    tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%; scrolling = yes", src = "www/sample_label.pdf")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
 output$downloadLabel <-  downloadHandler(
    
    filename = "www/sample_label.pdf",
    content = function(file) {    
      file.copy("temp.pdf", file)
    }
  )
     
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can successfully render an image from the folder using the following code although it sometime intermittently won't work when running the shinyApp(ui, server) function. It won't recognise any other document types in the folder. 'tags$img(src="www/sample_image.jpg", height = "200px", width = "200px", alt = "Not Found", deleteFile = FALSE)'

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, separating the combined app.r file into ui.r and server.r files, setting the working directory to the folder containing these files plus the www folder, and then using runApp() seems to do the trick.